# Pass a variable from one class to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass one variable from a class to another one. I tried doing it and searched the web but I can't really find out what I was looking for. I have 2 classed names; class1, class2. I am trying to create a variable called self.v in class1 and try to pass it to class2. This is what I have tried so far...

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create()
    def create(self):
        self.v = 6

class class2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def print(self,c1):
        print(self.v)

c = class1()
c1 = c.create()
c2 = class2()
c3 = c2.print(c1)
```

I also tried doing this:

```
class class1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.create()
    def create(self):
        self.v = 6

class class2(object):
    def __init__(self,class1):
        self.print(class1)
    def print(self,class1):
        print(self.v)

c = class1()
c1 = class2(c)
```

.. but that didn't really help fix but the problem either. If someone could please help me, I would appreciate a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Have you already worked through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)? If not, you should do before trying more complicated things.

Comment: Hint: in your first attempt, `print` takes an argument `c1` that you aren't doing anything with. Maybe you *should* be doing something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If class2 needs an instance of class1, one obvious solution is to pass the class1 instance to the class2 initializer:

```
class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self, c1):
        self.c1 = c1
    def print(self):
        print(self.c1.v)

c1 = Class1(6)
c2 = Class2(c1)
c2.print()
```